# Stagger divswhen they are in view using react-intersection-observer and framer-motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion, react-intersection-observer

I'm working on a React app and I want to add some animations using react-intersection-observer and framer-motion.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-minsky-d43sr5?file=/src/App.js:0-1730)

So far, everything is working correctly. All my divs are animating when they are in view.

But I want to add staggering to these div boxes.
I want the `h1` from the black box to fade in, then the `h1` from the gray box, the `h1` from black box again, then `h1` from the gray one etc. As you scroll, I want the same staggering effect.

I tried using staggerChildren, but with no real success.

```
import "./styles.scss";
import { motion, useAnimation } from "framer-motion";
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const boxItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "box-1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "box-2"
  }
];

function FadeInWhenVisible({ children }) {
  const controls = useAnimation();
  const [ref, inView] = useInView();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inView) {
      controls.start("visible");
    }
  }, [controls, inView]);

  return (
    <motion.div
      className="container-inner"
      ref={ref}
      animate={controls}
      initial="hidden"
      transition={{ duration: 1.2 }}
      variants={{
        visible: { y: 0, opacity: 1 },
        hidden: { y: 5, opacity: 0 }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </motion.div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <FadeInWhenVisible>
          {boxItems.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id} className="box">
              <h1>{item.title}</h1>
            </div>
          ))}
        </FadeInWhenVisible>
        <FadeInWhenVisible>
          {boxItems.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id} className="box">
              <h1>{item.title}</h1>
            </div>
          ))}
        </FadeInWhenVisible>
        <FadeInWhenVisible>
          {boxItems.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id} className="box">
              <h1>{item.title}</h1>
            </div>
          ))}
        </FadeInWhenVisible>
        <FadeInWhenVisible>
          {boxItems.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id} className="box">
              <h1>{item.title}</h1>
            </div>
          ))}
        </FadeInWhenVisible>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```